# How to point to a single file with external table

Tags: hive

Im trying to load hdfs data as external but get the following error.

The folder ml-100k has multiple datasets with different datasets, so I just need to load that particular file.

```
hive> create external table movie_ratings (movie_id int, user_id int, ratings int, field_4 int) location 'hdfs://hadoop-master:8020/user/hduser/gutenberg/ml-100k/u.data'
    > ;
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. MetaException(message:hdfs://hadoop-master:8020/user/hduser/gutenberg/ml-100k/u.data is not a directory or unable to create one)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot create a table that points to a file, only to a directory,  but there is a feature/bug that allows you to alter the location to a specific file.

```
create external table movie_ratings (movie_id int, user_id int, ratings int, field_4 int) location 'hdfs://hadoop-master:8020/user/hduser/gutenberg/ml-100k';

alter table movie_ratings set location 'hdfs://hadoop-master:8020/user/hduser/gutenberg/ml-100k/u.data';
```

Comment: How do I load only u.data if the filename is removed?

Comment: I wrote that I'm still editing the answer :-) see updated answer

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create a Hive table over a specific file, you need to give a directory.
So you can create a subdirectory under `ml-100k/` and use it like this :

```
create external table movie_ratings (movie_id int, user_id int, ratings int, field_4 int) location 'hdfs://hadoop-master:8020/user/hduser/gutenberg/ml-100k/new_subfilder/'
```

The bug mentioned by @Dudu may solve a specific case, but its not safe for general use, because inserting into such table will create new files and will never append the specified one !

Comment: Why do you think this is a bug?

Comment: Because its not accepted while creating, and accepted while altering, and because the reason mentioned in my answer.

Comment: So maybe the 'create' just has a missing functionality. That doesn't indicates a bug. Although the ability to read a specific file seems totally reasonable.  If there are issues with the write operation than only the insert can be blocked by design and not the select.